# Запретить прошедших дат и прошедших часов

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

Всем привет! Каким образом можно установить Mindate чтобы день, месяц, год можно было выбирать не раньше чем сегодняшняя дата и выбирать время не раньше время сейчас + 3 часа. Спасибо!

Comment: WinForms, прошу прощения что сразу не уточнил

Comment: `dateTimePicker.MinDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);`